# Combining functors and monads

Tags: haskell, monads, functor, applicative, option-type

I'm a haskell newbie and don't know, how to combine following functions in an expressive way:

```
f :: A -> B
g :: B -> Maybe C
h :: C -> Bool
```

I want a function like this:

```
y :: A -> Bool
```

Currently I'm doing it like that:

```
y a = case (fmap h ((g.f) a)) of {
            Just b -> b;
            Nothing -> False}
```

Well, I think, this is really ugly (Ok, here are only letters as names, but the real code is ugly, too). What I want is a concatenation of the functions, which is more expressive, like:

```
y a = (h.g.f) a `or` False
```

How is it possible to combine monadic functions with functors and is there something like `or` (like `Optional#orElse` in Java 8?)

Comment: You don't need so many parentheses in your case statement: `case fmap h . g . f $ a of ...`. Also, since it's indented properly, you don't need the braces or the semicolon either. By the way, this only involves the `Functor` instance for `Maybe`, not `Monad`. We are only using a method from `Functor` (`fmap`) and no methods from `Monad`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way would be to use the [maybe](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.3.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:maybe) function:

```
y :: A -> Bool
y a =  maybe False h (g $ f a)
```

Or as [Zeta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1139697/zeta) points out, you can use the pointfree notation:

```
y = maybe False h . (g . f)
```

Comment: Do I understand it right, that in the pointfree style, it's like:
`maybe (False) (h.(g.f))` in
`maybe :: (Bool) -> (a -> Bool -> Maybe a) -> Bool`?

Comment: @F.Böller: Nope. Have a look at the types: `maybe False h :: Maybe C -> Bool`, `g . f :: A -> Maybe C`. It's really `(maybe False h) . (g . f)`.

Comment: @Zeta: Ok, now I understand.

Answer (score 5):

The thing to recognize is that you're considering Nothing to be falsey, but Haskell doesn't assume that by default: you need to tell it.

```
smash :: Maybe Bool -> Bool
smash Nothing = False
smash (Just v) = v

-- or
smash = maybe False id
```

Then you can chain your operations along with the smashing

```
it :: A -> Bool
it = smash . fmap h . g . f
```

Edit: to be clear, this is exactly your code—just prettified a bit!

Comment: Isn't `maybe False id` the same as `fromMaybe False`?

Comment: Yep, but you don't have to import `maybe` and it's a bit more canonical, so I rarely use `fromMaybe`.

Comment: For my poor, limited mind, `fromMaybe x . fmap f` is easier to think about than `maybe x f`.